# regex split string on whitespace and other chars

Tags: java, regex, string, split

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+)\\s(.+)\\s(.?)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
System.out.println("Method:");  
System.out.println(m.group(1));
System.out.println(m.group(2));
```

The code above is my code I use to split this string:

```
method(public, static, void) main(String[] args){
```

I want to be able to get `method(public, static, void)` in a string and `main(String[] args)` in another string. I don't want the last `{` and there may be be spaces between the `)` and the `{`.

My code so far does this:

```
Method:
method(public, static, void) main(String[]
args){
```

I am not any good at regex. (My code doesn't currently handle the last `{`, but I can fix this.) The problem is that I cannot get the line to split how I want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `Pattern` and `Matcher` here. You should rather use `String#split()` method to `split` your string on `)`, and get first two elements of your array: -

```
String str = "method(public, static, void) main(String[] args){";

String[] parts = str.split("\\)");

System.out.println(parts[0]);  // method(public, static, void
System.out.println(parts[1]);  // main(String[] args
```

But, the problem that you can see is, your strings won't contain the last `)` in them.

To include the delimiter in the array elements, you can use *look-behind* on your regex: - `"(?<=\\))"`. Now, this will split your string on `empty character` preceded by `)`.

**This is what you need: -**

```
String[] parts = str.split("(?<=\\))");  // split on empty character after )
System.out.println(parts[0]);
System.out.println(parts[1]);
```

**output: -**

```
method(public, static, void)
 main(String[] args)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, so glad that it works, i can not believe i did not think of that. :)

Answer (score 1):

This

```
String str = "method(public, static, void) main(String[] args){";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{Alnum}+\\([^)]*?\\)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

produces following output:

```
method(public, static, void)
main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you match on:

```
/([^\(\)]+\([^\)]+\))([^\(\)]+\([^\)]+\))/
```

you should get back exactly what you need in `$1` and `$2`